# Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen der Geist und der Sinn?

Tags: difference

Worin besteht der Unterschied zwischen der Geist und der Sinn? Sie bedeuten beide "mind", nicht wahr?

Comment: Nein, das ist im Allgemeinen nicht korrekt. "The Germans have no mind und die Engländer haben keinen Geist" (from one of Guy Deutscher's books).

Answer (score 7):

The German words »Geist« and »Sinn« have very different meanings. Their fields of meaning overlap, but only in a small area.

»Geist« is, depending on context, one of these:

- mind
- ghost (Geisterbahn = ghost train)
- spirit (Weingeist = alcohol (spirits of wine); heiliger Geist = holy spirit)

»Sinn« is one of these:

- meaning (eigentlicher Sinn = classical meaning)
- mind
- sense (sechster Sinn = sixth sense)
- tenor

There is no German word that is an exact translation of the English word »mind«, and there is no English word, that is an exact translation of the German word »Geist«.